# Mailbox in which email landed

Tags: php, email, email-client

I am researching on to find the name of mailbox in which email landed. Suppose as an email Service Provider we are sending out clients email on clients data(subscribers), for showing reports we are doing research to find is it possible to get the mailbox status(Inbox/Spam) for the send data using PHP ,POP3/IMAP.
Any help will be considered highly valuable in our research.

Comment: I had included imap tag as we are using script built in PHP/IMAP to automatically read mail box .

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. What happens with the mail depends entirely on the configuration the  end-users have set up.